# ¿Se puede implementar @import y @font-face en un mismo proyecto?

Tags: html5, css3

He descargado las fuentes de Google Fonts y quiero saber si es posible utilizar @import y @font-face en un mismo proyecto para por si acaso alguna de las 2 formas de cargar fuentes no funciona. ejemplo:

```css
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900';

@font-face {
  font-family: robotoReplacement;
  src: url(Roboto-light.ttf),
       url(Roboto-thin.ttf),
       url(Roboto-Regular.ttf),
       url(Roboto-Medium.ttf),
       url(Roboto-Bold.ttf),
       url(Roboto-black.ttf); 
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', robotoReplacement;
}

p {
  font-weight: normal;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

¿Es posible?

Comment: No veo porque no, ¿has tenido algón problema con eso?

Comment: Esto sólo hará la carga más lenta sin ningún beneficio, saludos.

Comment: Deberías de usar tan solo la fuente guardada en local dado que es más eficiente y seguro

Comment: Claro que se puede, si no funciona una, fubciona la otra

Comment: @hakai ¿Por qué es más eficiente y seguro usar una fuente guardada en local? Tenía entendido lo opuesto (al menos en cuanto a eficiencia)

Comment: @Alvaro Montoro, es mas seguro por que al estar guardada en local la fuente no se pierde en caso de que el servidor remoto este caido, por otra parte al no tener que hacer una peticion remota a ese servidor, tarda menos en cargarla.

Comment: @hakai entendí seguridad de otra manera, yo a eso lo llamo fiabilidad. Sobre la petición remota, eso no es del todo correcto: tendrás una conexión a otro servidor que puede (o no) ser más lento que el que sirve la página, no tiene por qué tardar más en cargar la fuente. Con CDN/Google Fonts puede que otro sitio ya haya usado la fuente y el navegador la tenga disponible tardando mucho menos en cargar. También al tenerlas en tu propio servidor estarías usando una conexión adicional para cargar la fuente, lo que hará que el resto de contenido tarde más en cargarse (por los límites de conexiones)

Answer (score 1):

Sí, ya que son dos cosas diferentes.

El `@import` es para importar otro fichero de hojas de estilo (.css) y el `@font-face` es exclusivamente para añadir fuentes de texto.

Encontrarás más información en este enlace:

http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/advanced/atrules/

[html](/questions/tagged/html)[css](/questions/tagged/css)